# Is there a way to lock a specific application, in ubuntu, with 'sudo' method

Tags: firefox, root, lock, privileges

For instance, if I needed to lock firefox, and whenever someone needs to access it (under the same username as mine) the usual sudo password prompt should appear. I have disabled password prompt by default under visudo by giving my username 'nopasswd' privilege.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

as you have mentioned in your question that , if you want to lock an application that could be accessed by only root means , just change the permissions.

```
sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/firefox
sudo chmod 700 /usr/bin/firefox
```

for example I made it for pidgin:

```
jai@frank-Jai:~$ sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/pidgin
[sudo] password for jai: $$$$$$
jai@frank-Jai:~$ sudo chmod 700 /usr/bin/pidgin
jai@frank-Jai:~$ pidgin
 bash: /usr/bin/pidgin: Permission denied

jai@frank-Jai:~$
```

next time onwards if you would like to open firefox means type as

```
sudo firefox
```

Please note that in some rare cases (but it is something that is true for e.g. Firefox and Chromium), when a command is called, there is a script that is called first and then it is the one that launches the "normal" program executable. If you disable the script from running you will prevent anyone from running the application normally (e.g. from shortcuts or commands e.g. `firefox`). If someone knows where the "normal" executable of that application is located, then he will be able to launch it without any problem through a terminal. In order to avoid this, you have to change the permissions of that executable as well. Firefox's executable is located at `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox`.

For Deluge as OP mentioned :

Deluge Consists of `Deluge` and `Deluge-gtk` . so you have to do that for both .

Comment: @hakermania I agree with you but he asked for an example.So I did mention that.

Comment: I tried the above and it worked, well...for firefox. Then I tried it with compiz-config and deluge and ubuntu tweak. unfortunately deluge is still accessible from the launcher! Yet from a terminal, it says "permission denied". why's this happeing I wonder?

Comment: I'm guessing deluge is calling a script which then runs the gui (since deluge has a separate daemon thread).

Comment: @PythonStudent I have found that , Deluge have two types. `deluge` and `deluge-gtk`. so you have to block both the things.

Comment: That settles it! Thankyou rajagenupula. That was a quick and effective response. One more thing, just in case, how can one reverse these settings? (adding '-' before the commands?)

Comment: @PythonStudent . If you want to reverse it again then all you need to change the owner of the application file. Better than me this link can explain. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

Comment: This answer should include some kind of warning that running internet facing applications like firefox or pidgin is a terrible idea. This grants easy root privileges to hackers via [Cross Stie Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) for example.

Comment: @rajagenupula It's enough `chmod 766`

Comment: I gave him what he wanted. If you know the better than me no problem. Please post your answer.I always answer what I knew and what I have learned.

Comment: @rajagenupula It was just a comment. For this are the comments... to comment :)

Comment: Linux mint 20.1 `Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.`

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the owner of the applications in Ubuntu is root. For example check the applications from `/usr/bin`. You can check this with `ls -l /usr/bin`. For Firefox Web Browser, the result is:

```
ls -l /usr/bin/firefox
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 aug  3 23:37 /usr/bin/firefox -> ../lib/firefox/firefox.sh
```

So, to lock Firefox for other users than root, you need to take out the execute permission for group and others. You can do this with the following command:

```
sudo chmod 766 /usr/bin/firefox
```

or

```
sudo chmod go-x /usr/bin/firefox
```

[image: lock firefox]