# unlock app from root

Tags: root, pidgin, unlock

i tried to lock pidgin application through the following code written on another thread

```
 jai@frank-Jai:~$ sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/pidgin

[sudo] password for jai: $$$$$$

jai@frank-Jai:~$ sudo chmod 700 /usr/bin/pidgin

jai@frank-Jai:~$ pidgin

 bash: /usr/bin/pidgin: Permission denied

jai@frank-Jai:~$
```

this has locked the app but now clicking on the app its not opening. it should ask for the password i suppose but thats not happening any way to unlock the app ? or i went wrong somewhere in locking?

Comment: With what reason would you do such a drastic thing, and what was the post that advised you to?

Comment: Which post are you referring to?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/335404/is-there-a-way-to-lock-a-specific-application-in-ubuntu-with-sudo-method   this post is there no way to unlock?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Can't you find a "milder" solution here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/548568/how-to-block-specific-apps-from-opening-in-specific-accounts/548889#548889 or here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/445145/password-for-apps/445184#445184? You cannot run pidgin now because only root has permission run it. (and a password is only asked when you use `gksu <application>`.

Comment: my laptop will be accessed by my friends and i dont want them to read my messages thats why i am finding a way to lock an app and for opening it, it should ask for password

Comment: There is this thing called Guest Session @ShubhiDimri

Comment: @JacobVlijm my bad luck i couldn't see it is there any way to revert the things?

Comment: See the links in my comment above. The answer in your link is a bad one IMO, look at the comments to it.

Comment: this is what pidgin should be: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root. resetting the permissions will do the job. (755 indeed, as suggested by @Wilf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should already be owned by root so the `chown` command is not necessary - this:

```
sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/pidgin
```

Changes the ownership and group to be owned by root - it probably was owned by root in the first place, as could of be shown by `ls -l /usr/bin/*`, so was not necessary.

This command is what 'locks' the app:

```
sudo chmod 700 /usr/bin/pidgin
```

This change the permissions so the pidgin can only be read, written to, and executed by the owner *(in the case, root - manual for `chmod` [here](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html))*. So to run it, you would have to run it as root with something like:

```
#sudo pidgin
```

<sup>Without the `#`. but DON'T RUN IT</sup>

However, that is **a really bad idea (SO DON'T RUN IT)**, as any malicious code *(there shouldn't be, but some things online can be evil)* that is run could infect the system as root has access to everything - also as it run as root it can't use any of the configuration you made as your normal user, as root is a different user entirely.

To 'unlock' it so you can access it, run:

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/pidgin
```

This changes the permissions back.

To lock an app, try the answers @Jacob [suggested above](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567296/unlock-app-from-root/567302#comment781399_567296):

> Can't you find a "milder" solution here: [askubuntu.com/questions/548568/…](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548568/how-to-block-specific-apps-from-opening-in-specific-accounts/548889#548889) or here: [askubuntu.com/questions/445145/password-for-apps/445184#445184](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445145/password-for-apps/445184#445184)? You cannot run pidgin now because only root has permission run it. (and a password is only asked when you use `gksu <application>`

Also, with commands you find on the internet *(most on this site are ok - check all of the answer, the other answers, and comments first though)*, it may be ideal (particularly when run with `sudo` as root) to look up info on the command with `chmod --help`, `man chmod`, or online, so you can find out what the command actually does.

Comment: that just solved the problem but theres one more now ie every time i start ubuntu it ask for "unlock keyring" every time i have to enter password how this can be cured?

Comment: What for? This probaly is something different, when you have setup and online account such as email etc, for some programs is stores the password in a keyring - try this question: http://askubuntu.com/q/495957/178596 . Did you run chmod on any other programs?

Comment: thanks a lot everyting is fine now i deleted my online account and now its not asking for unlock keyring, thanks a lot